# RewriteRule при переносе файлов из корня в директорию

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Раньше много файлов проекта лежало в корне. В том числе в корне были такие файлы:

```
index.php
make.php
```

Чтобы навести порядок, вышеуказанные файлы были переложены в папку /operation/

Вопрос: как написать правило переадресации в .htaccess так, чтобы все ссылки вида

```
https://myproject.ru/ 
https://myproject.ru/?var=value 
https://myproject.ru/make.php
```

продолжили работать, и чтобы клиент даже не догадался, что на самом деле обращение идет к файлам

```
https://myproject.ru/operation/
https://myproject.ru/operation/?var=value
https://myproject.ru/operation/make.php
```

Если я указываю такие правила в файле .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?$ /operation/
RewriteRule ^/(.*\.php)$ /operation/$1
```

то страница https://myproject.ru/ открывается нормально, а вот вызов https://myproject.ru/make.php не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогла такая настройка:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /operation/$1 [NC]
```